# How to save uploaded images into different folders in mvc.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I have 4 upload textboxes and one submit button I want to save 4 images into 4 folders depending on textbox sequence.

Problems I am facing are:

I get file using HttpPostedFileBase so I can't differentiate which file came from which text box.

Comment: why do you need textboxes ??

Comment: Sorry, I mean file like  <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have 4 different input controls with 4 different names and in controller 4 different file bases ... and based on the control name you can save it to different folders

In your View

```
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
<input type="file" name="file3" />
<input type="file" name="file4" />
```

In your Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file1,HttpPostedFileBase file2,HttpPostedFileBase file3,HttpPostedFileBase file4)
{

}
```

Comment: hey @REDEVI_, Is your code tested? is it works as you post your form?

Comment: Thanks ! I have wasted so much time on it.